# python write into js file with umlauts

Tags: javascript, python

I would to write into js file with umlauts.

**My libs:**

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

**My input:**

```
[['10086', 10003, '29A.1 Sch\xc3\xa4tzung Mittel, Varianz, Standardabweichung; Stichprobe; OpenOffice.org; robuste Statistik', '00:29:16', 0.89868785807252183, 'method_onlyFT'], ['10108', 10004, 'K01 Ungleichung', '00:14:58', 0.87930209508145918, 'method_onlyFT']]
```

**My code:**

```
with open('gm_auto_'+str(1)+'.js', 'w') as js_out:
    for a in csvOut:    
         js_out.write(repr(a))
```

**My output:** is still without umlauts

The same with:

```
with open('masterCsv.txt', 'w') as masterCsv:
    for c in csvOut:
        wtr = csv.writer(masterCsv, delimiter= ';')
        wtr.writerows(c)
```

works well. I thing this is because of write(). How can I solve this?

Comment: I'm not sure what a `js` file is supposed to be, but why wouldn't you use JSON?

Comment: Your input looks fine, use a `json` file instead of a `csv/js construct` to bypass the encoding issues (if possible). Elsewise have a look at the [csv docs >> ](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples)

Comment: @DanielRoseman this ist javaScript, but I can write txt too. In both doesnt work...

Comment: @MauriceMeyer I tried this: with open('gm_auto_'+str(1)+'.json', 'w') as js_out:
 for a in csvOut: 
  js_out.write(repr(a)). This doesnt work.

Comment: The point is that you shouldn't be using `repr` for this kind of thing. Use `json.dumps`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman with open('gm_auto_'+str(1)+'.txt', 'w') as js_out:
 for a in csvOut:
  json.dump(a, js_out) still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily write the data into a `json` file, which is the preferred way to shared data in javascript.
As a side note: The array datastructure stay the same in `result.json`, so there is no need to convert the array to csv and way back in JS.

```
import json

data = [['10086', 10003, '29A.1 Sch\xc3\xa4tzung Mittel, Varianz, Standardabweichung; Stichprobe; OpenOffice.org; robuste Statistik', '00:29:16', 0.89868785807252183, 'method_onlyFT'], ['10108',
10004,
'K01 Ungleichung', '00:14:58', 0.87930209508145918, 'method_onlyFT']]

with open('/tmp/result.json', 'w') as output:
        output.write(json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: For your solution there is an error: TypeError: dump() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: But I solved the problem with: with open('gm_auto_'+str(1)+'.js', 'w') as js_out:
 for a in csvOut:
  json.dump(a, js_out, ensure_ascii=False)

Comment: Yes, i was using `dumps` instead of `dump` :)